# Why does GetProcAddress not work with OutputDebugString function

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, getprocaddress

I have been trying to use `GetProcAddress` with several functions from kernel32.dll. It worked fine, except with "OutputDebugString" function.

My code:

```
typedef void(WINAPI *LPGETNUMBER)(LPCTSTR);

int main() {
    const LPGETNUMBER pAddr = (LPGETNUMBER)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle((LPCSTR)("kernel32.dll")), "OutputDebugString");
    if (NULL == pAddr) {
        int32_t nLastErrorCode = GetLastError();
    }
}
```

Comment: And *how* doesn't it work? What errors do you get? And please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: A hint though: Almost all functions handling strings have *two* versions: One for ASCII and one for Unicode (using ***W***ide characters). They are implemented as two differently named functions.

Comment: sorry, my first question here. "how doesn't it work?" - pAddr is a null pointer

Comment: sorry, my first question here. "how doesn't it work?" - pAddr is a null pointer. What errors do you get? - I get error code of 127 (The specified procedure could not be found.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such function. The exports are named `OutputDebugStringA` and `OutputDebugStringW`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362

Comment: thank you! I missed that when I checked the documentation!

Answer (score 3):

The `OutputDebugString` is a macro expanding to either `OutputDebugStringA` or `OutputDebugStringW` depending on whether you are building with ANSI or Unicode. So you need to choose one of those (preferably, but not necessarily, depending on your build mode).